# Trace/Debug ansible-playbook variable resolution

Tags: ansible

ansible-playbook has a fairly complex variable precedence hierarchy.
In one case I am having trouble figuring out where a variable value is being resolved from.
I'm expecting it to come from group_vars but it isn't.

Is there a simple way to print where a variable value is coming from?

Hoping For something like:
max_mem: roles/app/defaults/main.yml

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to know. Moreover, Ansible have some crazy bugs with skewed priorities for included roles (f.e. 'role defaults' override 'set_facts' in included roles).