# How to find out which vars files are read when by ansible-playbook

Tags: debugging, ansible

I would like to understand which vars files are read when by ansible-playbook. But even with the option -vvvvvv, there are no entries in the output log regarding vars files.

How can I find out which vars files are read when by ansible-playbook?

Comment: Could you share your playbook code?

Comment: Ansible can read [variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html) from quite a few places. How we organize them, is our choice. Sticking to a standard makes it easier.

Comment: You should ask this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). Your question is about `tools used for administering ... automating ...`

Comment: The question of [Understanding variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) comes up sometimes, see in example [How to trace/debug `ansible-playbook` variable resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974073/). And because of that, you'll probably not be able to find out when where a variable got's a value as it depends on how you are organized.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how do you load the variables.

If you're talking about vars files, you're most likely using `include_vars` module. In this case you can register its execution result and log the [`ansible_included_var_files`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#return-ansible_included_var_files) return value:

```yaml
- name: Load the variables
  include_vars:
    dir: path/to/directory
  register: var_loading_result

- name: Log the list of the loaded vars files
  debug:
    var: var_loading_result.ansible_included_var_files
```

Note that this is not a special variable but a unique result of a module execution. So this has to be done on every invocation of `include_vars` module.

If by "vars files" you mean the `group_vars`  and/or `host_vars` of inventories (which is not the same as the vars files), there's a special variable [`ansible_inventory_sources`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#term-ansible_inventory_sources) to list them, but it doesn't allow to list the specific files if an inventory was specified as a directory.